# Can't access apache2 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I try to start/restart/reload my apache2 in my laptop but the result is fail
the errors like this :

```
Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn: Invalid command 'exit', 
perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'start' failed. The Apache error log may have more information.
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: did you try `sudo service apache2 start` command?If it still shows the error then try to purge and reinstall apache2.

Answer (score 1):

Enable headers Module

```
sudo ln -sf /etc/apache2/mods-available/headers.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/headers.load
```

Restarting Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: now error like this : ln: failed to create symbolic link `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/headers.load': Permission denied

Comment: add sudo before..  check the edit

Comment: i have been add sudo before

Comment: what is the output of `ls -lid /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`

Comment: now error like this : Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn:
Invalid command 'exit', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: Then purge apache2 and reinstall. `sudo apt-get purge apache2` and then `sudo apt-get install apache2`

Comment: @user254556 You are welcome so please mark it as answer to help others